# efficiently load and access torch tensor

Tags: memory, torch

I have a big binary file (almost 2GB) containing float32. I load it by

`t = torch.FloatTensor(torch.FloatStorage(filename))`

I will keep accessing this big tensor for 1 to 2 hours when executing my program. I observed that it's very slow for the first 10 to 20 minutes.

Can anyone explain why and provide some advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its may be because

> OS caches things in memory, in the background, without you having to care about it...

[Preferred Handling of Large Files](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/torch7/E4SaoAEnit0/pHMSiCdOlrIJ)